# jQuery validation for from and to dates without any jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, validation

I have tried three set of code using Stack Overflow. I know that some parsing/date manipulation needed for jQuery validation.

The start date and end date validation needs to be implemented in my project. If I alert I'm able to get both the start and end date in my alert box.

1. The start and end date will be in the format DD-MM-YYYY
2. I don't want to use any jQuery validator plugin (.js files) other than my jquery.js file.
3. Just I need to check one condition that the end date is greater than start date.

In other words, a two line code to check the start and end date.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $( "#my_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    //first set of code 
    var date_ini = new Date($('#from_date').val()).getTime();
    var date_end = new Date($('#to_date').val()).getTime();
    if (date_ini < date_end) {
    alert('Invalid');
    }

    //second set of code
    var from = Date.parse($("#from_date").val());
    var to = Date.parse($("#to_date").val());
    if(from < to){
    alert("Invalid Date Range");
    }
    else{
    alert("Valid date Range");
    }

    //third set of code
    var startDate = new Date($('#from_date').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#to_date').val());
    if (startDate < endDate){
    alert('Invalid');
    }

    });
    });

    </script>


    <form id="my_form" class="my_form">
    <table>
    <tr><td>From Date</td><td><input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date"  /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>To Date</td><td><input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date"  /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? The above works, but you want it in only two-lines?

Comment: its not about two lines. just a simple jquery script. ;)

Comment: If you do **not** want to use a jQuery plugin, then please don't tag your question with a jQuery plugin.  ([tag:jquery-validate] is a plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $( "#my_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    //first set of code 
    var date_ini = getDate($('#from_date').val()) ;
    var date_end = getDate($('#to_date').val());

    if (date_ini < date_end) {
    alert('valid');
        //put code here to call server
    }
        else
        {
            alert('Invalid');
            return false;
        }



    });
    });

function getDate(input)
{
 from = input.split("-");
return new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);   
}
```

Click here to see the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SS597/1/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the default date parser is not able to parse a date in the given format `DD-MM-YYYY`, so write a parser of your own like

```
function parseDate(string){
    var parts = string.split('-');
    return new Date(+parts[2],+parts[1],+parts[0]);
}

$("#my_form").submit(function (event) {
    //first set of code 
    var date_ini = parseDate($('#from_date').val()).getTime();
    var date_end = parseDate($('#to_date').val()).getTime();
    console.log(date_ini, date_end)
    if (date_ini > date_end) {
        console.log('Invalid 1');
    }
});
```

`new Date('24-07-2014')` returns `Invalid Date`!

Comment: i dnt check your code, but thanks for your time, it is also simple.